# script not executing all the way through

Tags: bash, watch, archlinux, i3

I wanted to replace ifplugd with a script, a deamon-like script that will be launched at startup by i3. Everything works fine when launching it from terminal, but whenever i try to auto launch it at startup, it gets killed instantly.

The command i use to launch it as i3 starts up:

```
exec ./.scripts/ifwatch enp0s25>ifwatch.log
```

The log file content:

```
[17:00:54]:Setting enp0s25 up
[17:00:55]:Listening on enp0s25
```

The script it self:

```
#!/bin/sh
dev=$1
echo [$(date +'%H:%M:%S')]:Setting $dev up
sudo ip link set $dev up
echo [$(date +'%H:%M:%S')]:Listening on $dev
while watch -n 5 -g ip link show dev $dev;
do
    if [[ -n $(ip link show dev $dev |tr '\n' ' ' | grep -v 'NO-CARRIER') ]];
    then
        echo [$(date +'%H:%M:%S')]:$dev "connected! running dhcpcd"
        echo $(sudo dhcpcd $dev)
    else
        echo [$(date +'%H:%M:%S')]:$dev "disconnected! killing dhcpcd"
        echo $(sudo dhcpcd -k $dev)
    fi

done
```

I tried to launch it in a screen instance (from the i3config file) but it didn't even created the socket, I also tried not sending the watch output buffer to `/dev/null` but it didn't help. 
I'm assuming the process get's instantly killed because at every startup the timestamp of the log file changes.

Comment: That logfile content was not created by that script. Please show **matching** code and output.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't notice the log file was from an older version of the code.

Comment: @TMLKyza : What do you mean by _startup_? When the computer is booted?

Comment: With "startup" as I said a couples time during the question I was referring to i3's startup, basically when loads the config file. I wasn't referring to the boot procedure. Moreover i3 it's "launched" by lightdm.

Comment: `watch` runs a program over and over. When would it ever exit so the inside of your `while` loop could happen?

Comment: That is to say, `while foo; do bar; done` runs `foo`, *waits for it to exit*, and then runs `bar` and goes back to the beginning if `foo` exited successfully. `watch` doesn't exit -- either successfully or otherwise -- so it makes no sense in this context.

Comment: watch with the -g option exits whenever a change in the output of the command changes

Comment: Ahh. Is it actually doing so in practice, when you trace your script's execution? I wouldn't be surprised if `watch` doesn't work without a TTY.

Comment: ...anyhow, *personally*, I'd take watch out of the picture and implement your own logic; easier to debug, if nothing else, and no longer depending on a nonstandard tool that's neither part of bash nor POSIX-specified. `last_status=$(ip link show dev "$dev"); while :; do new_status=$(ip link show dev "$dev"); if [[ $new_status != "$last_status" ]]; then last_status=$new_status; ...logic here...; fi; sleep 5; done`

Comment: ...speaking of "easier to debug", `set -x` with stderr redirected to a log file is always a good habit to be in when you're trying to track something down. (That is: `exec 2>/path/to/your.log; set -x` as the second line of your script will make a trace of each line written go to `your.log`).

Comment: it works if launched in a terminal, i was thinking the same thing too, so i decided to try and launch it from the i3 config file in a screen socket (exec screen ./.scripts/ifwatch enp0s25>ifwatch.log) but it doesn't even create one

Comment: You'll want to fix the [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) too. `echo $(thing)` is just a buggy and inefficient way to  say `thing` (unless you specifically require the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the output from `thing`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) suggested i wrote a function to do the job of `watch -g` and now it works perfectly. As he said probably `watch` does not work outside of a TTY.

Here's the code if anyone's intrested:

```
#!/bin/sh
dev=$1
sleeptime=5

function watcher {
    state1=$(ip link show dev $dev) 
    state2=$state1
    while [ "$state1" == "$state2" ];
    do
        sleep $sleeptime
        state2=$(ip link show dev $dev)
    done
    return 0
}


echo [$(date +'%H:%M:%S')]:Setting $dev up
sudo ip link set $dev up
echo [$(date +'%H:%M:%S')]:Listening on $dev
while watcher;
do
    if [[ -n $(ip link show dev $dev |tr '\n' ' ' | grep -v 'NO-CARRIER') ]];
    then
        echo [$(date +'%H:%M:%S')]:$dev "connected! running dhcpcd"
        sudo dhcpcd $dev
    else
        echo [$(date +'%H:%M:%S')]:$dev "disconnected! killing dhcpcd"
        sudo dhcpcd -k $dev
    fi

done
```